# Excluding $ in a regex in CF

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am working through some different form validation  types and I am having trouble getting all the items on my wishlist to work.

My code  for my cfinput is this (works the same as a regular form input and has some canned javascript validation)

```
    <cfinput type="Text" name="negdays" 
        range="0,23" 
        pattern="^(([^0]{1})([0-9])*|(0{1}))?$" 
        message="Negative Days must be a number between 0 and 23" 
        required="No"  width="2" >
```

This one should, and does, exclude everything  I need except the `$`. I am having difficulty stopping the form from accepting the `$`.

Another example that is similar is this one where I want a range and to keep it numeric, so I mixed the validation types

```
    <cfinput type="text" name="achamount" 
        validate = "range,numeric" 
        range = "0,99999" 
        message="ACH Amount must be a range from 0 - 99999 and  numeric only" >
```

... and it works perfect - except for one problem:  a `$` is allowed.

So I thought maybe I could add to it with a regex like this:

```
    <cfinput type="text" name="achamount" 
        validate = "range,numeric,regex" 
        range = "0,99999"  
        pattern="^\d" 
        message="ACH Amount must be a range from 0 - 99999 and  numeric only" >
```

But my pattern is of course only to limiting it to numeric, which I am already doing. I need my pattern to exclude the dollar signs. But as a special character its not behaving like the other stuff I want to get rid of.

Any ideas or suggestions? Everything I have tried either does not work or breaks all the other validation on the page.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution: Matching Only Numbers

You don't need to specifically exclude `$` - to only allow numeric digits, you simply need to ensure every character matches `\d`.

To do this, you need to anchor the start and end of the regex to the start and the end of the input, which is done with the regex metacharacters `^` and `$` respectively. (If you ever need to use either of these characters as literals, prefix them with a backslash.)

So for an integer between 0 and 99999 you want:

```
^\d{1,5}$
```

Matching an integer between 0 and 23 works the same way thing, but the central part of the pattern needs to be complex, to ensure you don't get 24 or above:

```
^(?:[03-9]|1\d?|2[0-3]?)$
```

The three alternatives here are:
* `[03-9]` matches any single digit except 1 or 2.
* `1\d?` matches 1, or 1 followed by any digit.
* `2[0-3]?` matches 2, or 2 followed by any digit upto 3.

The `(?:`..`)` is to ensure the `^` and `$` still apply to the entire string.

(Of course, you could also just use `^\d{1,2}$` then later check if it's less than 24.)

#### Bonus Info: Excluding Characters

As above, you don't need to do this in this case, but if you encounter a situation where you did need to exclude `$`, you could do it either using a negative character class:

```
^[^$]{1,5}$
```

Or using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?:(?!\$).){1,5}$
```

This latter one is a bit more complicated, but it allows more flexibility so is useful to be aware of.

A lookahead is another form of anchor (it matches at a position, but doesn't consume the characters it matches). When used against a item that has a quantifier (the `{1,5}` bit) attached, you need to group both items together for it to apply correctly. *(i.e. If you only did `(?!\$).{1,5}` the negative lookahead would only be checked for the first character, not all five.)*

Note that outside of a character class `$` must be escaped as `\$` to prevent it's special meaning of "end of string anchor". Inside a character class it is just a regular character.

<sub>*(Hopefully this explanation is clear - let me know if further information or clarification would be useful.)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `^(([^0]{1})([0-9])*|(0{1}))?$` can be simplified quite a bit. It seems that you want either a single digit preceeded by a 0 or maximum 2 digits.

Try this: `^\d{2}$`

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the $ to a range of characters you don't allow?

```
pattern="[^$]"
```